# Retrieve value from database and put is as a selected option in <select> element

Tags: php, html, select, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to retrieve a value from my database and put it as a selected value in my `<select>` element, but the problem is that it is not showing the value retrieved in the `<select>` menu.

The variable $level contains the value "6ème", so the problem is not from an empty variable but from the select menu and the selected option I guess. Here is my code :

```
<select name="level" class="form-control selectpicker" value="05">
    <?php if($level="") {?> 
         <option value=" " > Please choose your level </option>
    <?php  }
    else {?> 

    <option selected="selected" value=" " > <?php echo $level; ?>  </option> <?php } ?>

    <option value="01">1st</option>
    <option value="02">2nd</option>

</select>
```

When I'm putting text instead of $level, it's showing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$level = '6ème';
?>
                <select name="level" class="form-control selectpicker" >
                        <?php if($level == "") {?> 
                             <option value=" " > Please choose your level </option>
                        <?php  } else { ?> 
                <option value="<?php echo $level; ?>" selected > <?php echo $level; ?>   </option> 
            <?php } ?>

                        <option value="01">1st</option>
                        <option value="02">2nd</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: Check the if condition

Answer (score 0):

you are setting $level = to empty string you should use == or ===
if that isn't your issue print_r or use a debugger like xdebug to track down if it is breaking in some other area.

Comment: Oh thanks ! the problem was = that I was using instead of == ! Thanks again ;)